# font-feature-settings for the entire website in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-feature-settings

I would like to display the letter "w" and "W" in another way on my website with `font-feature-settings.`

How can I do it dinamically on the entire website in JS?

What I need to add is `font-feature-settings: "ss03" 1`;

What I tried now is this. But this convert to paragraph all my text and I dont see any tatx styles anymore:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

  for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
    const paragraph = paragraphs[i];
    const text = paragraph.textContent;

    const replacedText = text.replace(/(W|w)/g, '<span class="ss03">$1</span>');

    paragraph.innerHTML = replacedText;
  }
});
</script>
```

EDIT: I was able to solve it in this way

```
// Get all elements on the page
const allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

// Loop through each element to find occurrences of 'w' and 'W'
for (const element of allElements) {
// Check if the element contains the text 'w' or 'W'
if (element.textContent.includes('w') || 
element.textContent.includes('W')) {
// Add the class ".ss03" to the element
element.classList.add('ss03');
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you use Unicode-range instead to bring in just those two characters from a different font? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range

Comment: Hi, I don’t understand your solution. Why doesn’t it change the look of att characters in the element? (Your span solution looked more feasible).